# php- how to show extra whitespaces on mysql db output?

Tags: php, mysql, string

I am saving records  like below in my MySQL database:

```
Name: Hello World                               Age: 17
Ref. by: Lorem Ipusm                            Sample: Blood

                         www.domainname.com

Investigations    Results            Units          N.Ranges
Haemoglobin       14.5               Gms%.          {13-18}
```

you might have got an idea ,i am doing the following:

```
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, nl2br($_POST['data']));
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (Data) VALUES ('$data')";
$exec = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
```

But when I am displaying the output, it removes all the extra whitespaces and shows output like:

```
Name: Hello World Age: 17
Ref by.: Lorem Ipsum Sample: Blood
www.domainname.com
Investigation Results Units N.Ranges
Haemoglobin 14.5 Gms%. {13-18}
```

All the alignment is messed up, any way to make what I want work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: @Fred-ii you should answer that in the answer box :)

Comment: @rezashamdani Thanks for the offer, but I'll pass on this one. Questions like these stand at getting closed, and in such a short "answer", well... the outcome can come as an unexpected surprise ;-)

Comment: i cant give you an up-vote if you answer on the comment only. 10+ is better that nothing

Answer (score 1):

As Fred-ii mentioned, you can wrap your output in `<pre></pre>` tags. HTML by default ignores any spaces past the first in output. See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1) for more information.

An alternative could also be replacing all spaces with `&nbsp;` which will force all the spaces to render out on the page.